# Node.js HTTPS server ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I created the server.key and server.csr files using `openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.csr`. I created a SSL certificate with startssl.com which gave me a certificate file. Then in my node.js application I read the key and certificate files:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
});
```

But, now I get an empty response from my application, a "No data received" message. What could be causing this? I'm very new to SSL and how it all works, so any help with this is very much appreciated.

More info: I generated the two files, key and csr files, on my VPS server (production server), and now I'm trying to get them to work on my localhost (firstly, before I commit my code to production; I have to test that it works before making a git commit). So, it could be due to the fact that my localhost (development environment) is on a different domain from my VPS server (production environment). Could this be the case? If so, how can I make it to where the localhost and production environment use the same certificate?

Or, would you suggest I create another certificate for my development environment? The only problem I see with that, is that I wouldn't have a domain for my dev environment because it's done locally. I'd rather much use the same certificate (even if that means a broken lock icon or something on localhost) for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can troubleshoot errors by connecting to your application with `curl --insecure --verbose`. Generally you shouldn't use an SSL certificate on more than one host. You can make a self-signed one to test locally and use the startssl one in production. But in any case, the CN in the cert needs to match the hostname used to connect to the site to avoid annoying browser warnings. You can always make up a domain name for your machine like `sam.local` and put that in your /etc/hosts file and use that in your self-signed certificate as well as your browser address bar.

Comment: Yeah, this is kinda what I've been figuring out through my research. Thanks for your answer though! :) But, a self signed cert wouldn't have a CA, or would it need one, or would it be the local machine, and if it was the local machine then how do I get my browser to recognize the local machine as a CA?

Comment: The self-signed cert would have a CA, but it would be one you generated and browsers have a bunch of CAs built in that they recognize. You can import your generated CA cert into your browser to get rid of the security warning.

Answer (score 43):

I know this is an old question, but I encountered the same thing today. I would get the same result back from express (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

The fix? Be sure to specify `https`, and not `http`, in your test browser (e.g., `https://localhost:8443`).

If you previously used middleware to forward all http requests to https you wouldn't have seen this problem before. Also, expect your browser to complain about the certificate, but proceed through anyway (in chrome this takes several clicks).

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed it for me

Comment: You, old user of the Internet, have saved me from 3 hours of cursing and willingness to kill myself.

Comment: Thanks. Same silly issue in my case as well