# Cannot open site with https server using Express

Tags: node.js, express, https

```
var fs = require('fs'),
https = require('https'),
express = require('express'),
app = express();

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/cert.pem')
}, app).listen(55555);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.header('Content-type', 'text/html');
  return res.end('<h1>Hello, Secure World!</h1>');
});
```

I tried many times about using https server based on express, while I still cannot open the site, for example using Chrome:

It says "No data received" and "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

So it is listening, but the response cannot be sent to client, why? 
Thank you!

Comment: This question seems to be duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318101/node-js-https-server-err-empty-response

Comment: I have found the answer, thank you @Ricardo Stuven

Comment: If you've found the answer, then post it below where it says "Your Answer".

Comment: This is similar to this [answer.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318101/node-js-https-server-err-empty-response