# Routes not working after setting up HTTPS with Express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

Im trying to set up my app with an HTTPS connection. After setting it up, Express stop routing requests that were coming in.

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl-cert.pem')
}

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
  console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  console.log('test');
  res.send('hello world')
});
```

I keep getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Does anyone know why this is?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what url are u calling?

Comment: I'm calling localhost:3000/

Comment: Possibly related: [Node.js HTTPS server ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318101/node-js-https-server-err-empty-response) and [Node.js app giving ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917590/node-js-app-giving-err-empty-response)

Comment: You HAVE to type `https://localhost:3000`.  You can't leave out the `https`.

Comment: How can i force express to automatically route to https if I type http? @jfriend00

Comment: You can do it with `Nginx` or `Apache` or redirect all http requests to https

Comment: There are at least a dozen answers here on stack overflow that show you how to redirect from http to https.  Here's one [Automatic HTTPS connection/redirect with node.js/express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23977269/816620).

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes, because you use `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` or (`http://127.0.0.1:3000/`), but you need to use `https` protocol (`https://localhost:3000/`) certificate for it, to make node.js catch this request