# nodeJS cannot get request despite working server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

After few months I wanted to launch my node server again. But it appears that despite server seems to be working fine I cannot get a view (or do anything else). I don't get any errors from console, just my browser send me ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. As well as curl which sends me "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". In fact I'm not ever directed to the app.get('/') function. I'm 100% positive that code was correct and I used it previously many times. So I'm a bit confused what could be wrong here:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config.json');

var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req, res){
 console.log('Am I here?'); // don't get that message 
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'index.html');
});


https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.node.certs.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.node.certs.cert)
    }, app)
    .listen(config.node.port, config.node.host, function (err) {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err)
        };
        //no errors here. I get the message below 
        console.log('server is running on port: ' + config.node.port);   
});
```

config.node is an object from external file where I store all variables related to launching my server (port: 5000, host: localhost) and path to my ssl certs. Furthermore when I change my https.createServer function to something simpler like "app.listen(5000)" it works fine. Do you know what is wrong with that piece of code and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is `app`? seems your example is incomplete

Comment: app is just an instance of express() object. I've updated my code to be more consistent. Please take a look

Comment: try changing `}, app)
    .listen(config...` to `}, app);
    app.listen(config...`

Comment: It doesn't look like a code problem, this message may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318101/node-js-https-server-err-empty-response